# docker-exec failed: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: exec, docker, cd

I used this command:
`docker exec compassionate_mclean cd /root/python`
 The error returned is

> docker-exec: failed to exec: exec: "cd": executable file not found in
>   $PATH

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 192, accepted):

`cd` is a built-in shell command, you can't set it as the command to run. You have to use:

```
docker exec -i compassionate_mclean bash -c "cd /root/python && python myscript.py"
```

If you want to see the output make sure to add the `-i` flag as shown above. In this case however, you can simply run python as your entrypoint:

```
docker exec -i compassionate_mclean python /root/python/myscript.py
```

Comment: But after this command I need to run a python script located at that directory.How do I do that?

Comment: But I can't stop the script by Ctrl + C in my local box, right? 
Because `bash -c` will run another child shell that I can't outside the docker container.

Comment: I think the `-i` is optional here

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ***-w*** option of the '*docker exec*'-command to set the working-folder as an absolute path in the container. But you would have to set it on every docker-call!

e.g.

```
docker exec -w /root/python compassionate_mclean python myscript.py
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that, you can do either `docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash` and then issue several commands with this interactive sessions, or `docker exec -d my_container touch myfile` if you just want to create a file, see the examples at https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#examples_3

Answer (score 0):

In my case I should cd into the subfolder first, where my celery file located. Then run the command

Answer (score -3):

If u execute docker container exec --help , it will show the options and method to execute the command 
Usage:  docker container exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

U have to use docker container exec -it [container_name] bash

Once u are in bash then u can execute any command you wish. Doing CD wont work.